# Adding "MENU" word beside hamburger icon - into strange code for me

Tags: html, css

I need add word "Menu" beside hamburger mobile icon. But the this css code is strange for me, or i don´t know why it doesn´t work.

This is the link http://test48.lukas-ptacek.cz/subdom/test48/uzivatele/vzor/ . Header menu is ok! But i need text "Menu" beside profile menu hamburger under profile photo cover.

Big thanks guys!

```
.yz-responsive-menu:after {
     content: 'MENU';
     font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif;
     font-style: normal;
     font-size: 12pt;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin-left: 30px;
   }
```

Here is whole css for this:

```
.yz-profile-navmenu .yz-navbar-item.yz-active-menu{border-bottom:4px solid}.yz-profile-navmenu .yz-navbar-item a:hover,.yz-profile-navmenu .yz-navbar-item a:hover i{color:#797676;background:0 0}.yz-profile-navmenu .yz-navbar-item a i{font-size:14px}.yz-navbar-inline-icons .yz-navbar-item a i{margin:0 10px 0 0}.rtl .yz-navbar-inline-icons .yz-navbar-item a i{margin:0 0 0 10px}.yz-navbar-block-icons .yz-navbar-item a i{display:block;margin:0 0 12px 0}.show-responsive-menu{display:block!important}.yz-responsive-menu{display:none;margin:0;top:24px;left:35px;width:22px;height:20px;font-size:0;z-index:9999;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;padding:0!important;background:0 0!important;min-width:initial!important;text-indent:-9999px;box-shadow:none;border-radius:0;border:none;cursor:pointer;-webkit-appearance:none;-moz-appearance:none;appearance:none}.yz-responsive-menu:focus{outline:0}.yz-responsive-menu span{display:block;position:absolute;top:7px;left:0;right:0;height:3px;background:#868e96}.yz-responsive-menu span::after,.yz-responsive-menu span::before{content:"";left:0;width:100%;height:3px;display:block;position:absolute;background-color:#868e96}.yz-responsive-menu,.yz-responsive-menu:hover{background-color:transparent}.yz-responsive-menu span::after,.yz-responsive-menu span::before{transition-duration:.3s,.3s;transition-delay:.3s,0s}.yz-responsive-menu span::before{top:-7px;transition-property:top,transform}.yz-responsive-menu span::after{bottom:-7px;transition-property:bottom,transform}.yz-responsive-menu.is-active{-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;background-color:transparent}.youzer .yz-responsive-menu.is-active span{background:0 0!important}.yz-responsive-menu.is-active span::before{top:0;-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);-ms-transform:rotate(45deg);transform:rotate(45deg)}.yz-responsive-menu.is-active span::after{bottom:0;-webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);transform:rotate(-45deg)}.yz-responsive-menu.is-active span::after,.yz-responsive-menu.is-active span::before{transition-delay:0s,.3s}.yz-profile-navmenu .yz-nav-view-more-menu{left:0;top:100%;z-index:9999;display:none;min-width:235px;text-align:left;position:absolute;background-color:#fff;-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 1px 0 rgba(164,166,167,.3);box-shadow:0 1px 1px 0 rgba(164,166,167,.3)}.rtl .yz-profile-navmenu .yz-nav-view-more-menu{text-align:right}.yz-profile-navmenu
```

Comment: What is strange in this css code? [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)

Comment: better said - I don´t know why this code doesn ´t work in this case on this web, it seems be easy, just add content: "Menu" , but its not. and don´t know where is problem  .yz-responsive-menu:after {
     content: 'MENU';

Comment: Maybe is problem in another place on code, or maybe i need to use different code especially for this profile hamburger menu . really don´t know :-D . That´s why i add link to web. I tried this figure out for many hours :-D ... Thanks for any help!

Comment: In your link, if i resize the window i see the content menu after the hamburger, so what's the problem? sorry i don't understand

Comment: sorry for my bad description . In my link, on phone, there is red header and "hamburger" menu with word "Menu" - this is how it should look . And lower, there is profile photo with cover image, and under this another hamburger menu. And I need add word "Menu" beside this hamburger menu, (just like above in red header). Just add "Menu" word. That´s it :)

Comment: Ok, if i inspect your code i don't see you css declaration for .yz-responsive-menu::after. and try to set the color maybe black, because you have a white background.

Comment: thanks for your comments man! :-) solution was on another place `.yz-responsive-menu:after {
        content: "Více";
        display: block;
        color: #848b92;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        margin-left: -41px;
        width: 100px;
        text-align: right;
margin-top: -5px !important;
    }

.yz-responsive-menu {
  overflow: visible;
      text-indent: -70px;
  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to remove the `overflow: hidden;` and `text-indent: -9999px;` from `.yz-responsive-menu` class, because pseudo elements will not be visible if the parent tag's overflow is hidden. also add the code given below. Hope this will help :)

```
 .yz-responsive-menu:after {
        content: "MENU";
        display: block;
        color: #848b92;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        margin-left: 35px;
        width: 100px;
        text-align: left;
    }
```

Comment: @luckyLukeBirdie gerat to hear that it helped ;)

Comment: Absolutely great man! :-) i used this code with small change `.yz-responsive-menu:after {
        content: "Více";
        display: block;
        color: #848b92;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        margin-left: -41px;
        width: 100px;
        text-align: right;
margin-top: -5px !important;
    }

.yz-responsive-menu {
  overflow: visible;
      text-indent: -70px;
  }`
so big big big thanks! :-)

Comment: So I wish you happiness for you life :) and thanks :)